# How to read floats from file in c?

Tags: c, file

I am struggling with reading floats from a file which I created during the program lifetime. I was trying to rewind the file, I was trying to open and close file before reading it, I was trying to put values directly in the table and by another variable. Idk what can I do more, what's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    float *tab;
    float x = 0.0;
    int i, size;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Size of table: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    tab = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tab[i] = (8.0 - 2.0) * (float)rand() / RAND_MAX + 2.0;
        fprintf(fp, "%.2f ", tab[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", tab[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    fp = fclose;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    tab = realloc(tab, 2*size);

    for (i = 0; i < size * 2; i+=2) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &x);
        printf("%.2f ", x);
        //tab[i + 1] = tab[i] / 2;
    }

    /*for (i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
        printf("%.2f \n", tab[i]);
    }*/


    fp = fclose;
    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Come on, now. If you have `float *tab;` like you do, then why do you think `tab = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));` makes any kind of sense? That kind of code probably will end up "working", but it obviously shows off a lot of confusion.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake. But that has no influence to read from file. The problem is the same :(

Comment: @xing doesnt work

Comment: xing's suggestion + `fopen( ... "r" )` for reading. "w+" truncates

Comment: And always check the return values of library calls - `malloc()` and `realloc()` may fail, and `system("PAUSE")` will certainly fail here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems in this code. First, as noted in the comments, the initial allocation is wrong. You are allocating space for `float`s, not `int`s. You could have avoided this problem entirely if you had written the call to `malloc()` like this:

```
tab = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * size);
```

Here, the result of `malloc()` is not cast, [since it is not necessary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, note that instead of using an explicit type for the argument to the `sizeof` operator, the identifier is used instead. This guarantees that whatever the type of `tab`, which must be a pointer, the result of `sizeof` will be correct. Also, you should always check to see if an allocation was successful.

`fp = fclose` is just wrong. This should be `fclose(fp)`. After this, when you open the file again with `"w+"`, the file is truncated to zero length, and you lose the data that was previously written. Since the file has already been opened with `"w+"`, just use `rewind(fp)` here.

For the reallocation that you do, aside from that the arguments are not quite right here, there is a potential problem that you should be aware of. `realloc()` can return a null pointer in the event of an allocation error. If this happens, and you are directly assigning the result of `realloc()` to the pointer for which you are reallocating (`tab`), then you will lose the reference to previously allocated memory. This is a memory leak, and lost data. The way to do this is to store the result of `realloc()` in a temporary pointer, which you test. If the temporary pointer is a null pointer, there was an error; otherwise you can safely assign the return value to the original pointer.

And as already noted, when you call `fclose()` the final time, it needs to be `fclose(fp)`.

Here is a modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    float *tab, *temp;         // added temp for realloc() check
    float x = 0.0;
    int i, size;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Size of table: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    /* You should always check for allocation errors */
    if ((tab = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in initial allocation\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tab[i] = (8.0 - 2.0) * (float)rand() / RAND_MAX + 2.0;
        fprintf(fp, "%.2f ", tab[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", tab[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

//    fclose(fp);                     // not fp = fclose;
//    fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");   // when you reopen, the file is truncated
    rewind(fp);                       // but just do this

    /* Fixed this reallocation */
    temp = realloc(tab, sizeof(*tab) * size * 2);    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in reallocation\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    tab = temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size * 2; i+=2) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &x);
        printf("%.2f ", x);
        //tab[i + 1] = tab[i] / 2;
    }

    /*for (i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
        printf("%.2f \n", tab[i]);
    }*/


    fclose(fp);            // not fp = fclose;
    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
Size of table: 10
2.65 5.67 5.21 3.22 3.07 4.29 5.96 5.96 5.15 7.36 
2.65 5.67 5.21 3.22 3.07 4.29 5.96 5.96 5.15 7.36
```